# using min_element on partial order

Tags: c++, graph, stl-algorithm

Can `std::min_element` (and also `std::sort` and similar functions from `<algorithm>`) be used on types with only a partial order?

For example:

```
auto it = std::min_element(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), [](const node* a, const node* b) {
    return a->precedes(*b);
});
```

Here `node` represents nodes in an DAG (directed acyclic graph), and `a.precedes(b)` tests it `a` is an ancestor of `b`. But if `a` and `b` are on different branches, it also returns `false`, and in that case `a.precedes(b) == b.precedes(a) == false`.

Comment: A partial ordering is not sufficient to use `std::min_element` and `std::sort` according to the standard, but a total ordering is not required, what you need is a strict weak ordering - See answer for more details and quotes from the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per §25.4/3 (emphasis and *foot-notes* are mine):

> For algorithms other than those described in 25.4.3<sup>*</sup> to work
>   correctly, comp<sup>**</sup> has to induce a **strict weak ordering** on the values.

<sub>*<sup>*</sup> 25.4.3 is the section for binary search algorithms.*</sub>
<sub>*<sup>**</sup> `comp` is the custom comparator.*</sub>

Since `std::sort` is defined in 25.4.1 and `std::min_element` is in 25.4.7, then you only need a **strict weak ordering** on the values, i.e.:

> The term strict refers to the requirement of an irreflexive relation (!comp(x, x) for all x), and the term weak to requirements that are not as strong as those for a total ordering, but stronger than those for a partial ordering. If we define equiv(a, b) as !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a), then the requirements are that comp and equiv both be transitive relations:
>
> (4.1) — comp(a, b) && comp(b, c) implies comp(a, c)
>
> (4.2) — equiv(a, b) && equiv(b, c) implies equiv(a, c)

As far as I understand your relation, it does not match the *equiv* requirement since you may have two nodes where `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)` but `a != b`. Typically, if you have `a` and `c` on one branch and `b` on another one, the above won't work because `equiv(a, b) == equiv(b, c) == true` but `equiv(a, c) == false`.

Answer (score 0):

From the C++11 standard § 23.2.1:

> `a < b` convertible to `bool`. `lexicographical_-compare(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end())` pre[condition]: `<` is defined for values of `T`. `<` is a **total ordering** relationship.

So, no that won't work.

Comment: This is a quote about comparison operators between two containers, how does this relates to `std::min_element` or `std::sort`?